# VideoCaptureElement NewVideoSample event never fired

Tags: c#, wpf, directshow, wpf-mediakit

I'm trying to use WPF-MediaKit `VideoCaptureElement` to preview a web cam video, and to decode QR code if one is in a frame, therefore I need to get access to each frame recorded by web cam and according to documentation it requires `EnableSampleGrabbing` option on and `NewVideoSample` event handler. 
As for now my code looks something like this.

```
public partial class QrScannerControl : UserControl
{
    public delegate void QrResultDelegate(string qr);

    public QrResultDelegate OnQrDeoded { get; set; }
    private QRCodeReader _qrCodeReader = new QRCodeReader();
    public QrScannerControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VideoCapElement.EnableSampleGrabbing = true;
        VideoCapElement.UseYuv = false;
        VideoCapElement.NewVideoSample += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new BitmapLuminanceSource(args.VideoFrame)));

            BitMatrix bm = binBitmap.BlackMatrix;
            Detector detector = new Detector(bm);
            DetectorResult detectorResult = detector.detect();

            var retStr = detectorResult.Points.Aggregate("Found at points ", (current, point) => current + (point.ToString() + ", "));

            Console.WriteLine(retStr);
            DebugLabel.Content = retStr;
            var result = _qrCodeReader.decode(binBitmap);
            if (result == null) return;
            OnQrDeoded?.Invoke(result.Text);
        }; 
    }
}
```

But the event never fires.

Comment: Probably similar to the [WPF-MediaKit issue #6](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit/issues/6) ?